# Permission is being denied on Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image: picture of error]

I don't know why I'm getting this error when I am running my project I would appreciate if some one could help me. I'm new to Flutter and Android Studio.

flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.11.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.11.0 at /Users/tobiadegoroye/flutter
    • Framework revision 856a90e67c (4 months ago), 2019-11-08 18:00:01 -0800
    • Engine revision af04338413
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tobiadegoroye/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: did you "flutter upgrade"? are you using an emulator with google apis? real device?

Comment: yh i recently upgrade flutter to a new version and i'm using a emulator as well

Comment: Could you try running `flutter doctor -vv` and provide the output here?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `gradlew` isn't set as an executable on your machine, and causes `ProcessException: Permission Denied` errors. Try running `chmod +x gradlew` on your Mac OS.